# Django: server global settings in

Tags: django, python-3.x

I don't know what I changed in previous  django project when I run any new project without setting any thing in urlpatterns it shows 
error
[image]

instead of original Django running 
[image]
I already tried uninstalling pycharm to deleting the project nothing works
urls.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

I used this piece of code in previous project

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: post your code snippets for `urls.py` and `views.py`

Comment: you are going to `/catalog` but where you have defined it in your `urls`

Comment: yes I don't know i defined it in previous project but I delete that project but it still referring to that project urls.py file